# Ajax call not returning excel file

Tags: ajax, excel, servlets, aem

I am running an ajax call to a servlet on click of a link. The link does not have the servlet called directly. Its called from an 'onClick' function instead.

```
$('#exportExcelLink').on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var docStatus=JSON.stringify(g_checkboxVal);
      $.ajax({     
          type : "GET",     
          url : '/bin/servlets/dashboardexcelexport',
          data : { docStatus: docStatus },
          contentType: 'application/json',

          success : function(data) { 
              console.log("excel export call success");
          },     
          error : function(data) {       
              console.log("error occured in excel export call");
          }           
      });
  });
```

I can see the excel being generated in my server logs and the response headers also show the file name and type (seen in network tab of console).
[image: Ajax call response headers]

But the file does not pop up for me to open or save. There is no activity on the page at all.

Do I need to do something else ?

Comment: Is there some reason why you're using ajax to download a file?

Comment: @Musa, I need to run a search based on the sent parameters  and then generate the excel file with the results. I did not find any other way to do so other than ajax to a servlet in the server side.

Comment: How about using a form

Answer (score 0):

Use the built-in createObjectURL method to create a URL with your Ajax response.  Then create a hidden link and make the href the object you created.  Then use JavaScript to click the link